# How to remove background color/action when click white space in Bootstrap Dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have a Bootstrap dropdown button with css and code below:

```
<style>     
    .dropdown-menu {
        max-height: 500px;
        max-width: 300px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }

    .dropdown-item {
        font-size: 30px;
        font-family: 'Times New Roman';
        
    }
</style>

<div class="dropdown">
   <button class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg dropdown-toggle" style="font-size: 20px; width: 200px; font-family: 'Times New Roman';" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" aria-haspopup="true" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                            Locaton List
                                        </button>
                                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
                                            <p class="dropdown-item">
                                                @foreach (var item in ViewBag.DDLLocations)
                                                {
                                                    <input type="checkbox" id="@item.Value" name="selectedLocations" value="@item.Value" />
                                                    <label for="@item.Value">@item.Text</label>
                                                    <br />
                                                }
                                            </p>
                                            
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

When I click the button the background will have action like I choose it somehow, and it become blue at background:
[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X50Cv.jpg)

How can I change it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Place your `css` after the Bootstrap css link

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<style>
  .dropdown-menu {
    max-height: 500px;
    max-width: 300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }

  .dropdown-item {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman';
  }

  .dropdown-item:active {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
  }
</style>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg dropdown-toggle" style="font-size: 20px; width: 200px; font-family: 'Times New Roman';" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" aria-haspopup="true" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Locaton List</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
    <p class="dropdown-item">
      <input type="checkbox" id="Value1" name="selectedLocations" value="Value1" />
      <label for="Value1">Text1</label><br />
    </p>
    <p class="dropdown-item">
      <input type="checkbox" id="Value2" name="selectedLocations" value="Value2" />
      <label for="Value2">Text2</label><br />
    </p>
    <p class="dropdown-item">
      <input type="checkbox" id="Value3" name="selectedLocations" value="Value3" />
      <label for="Value3">Text3</label><br />
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: using `!important` is rarely a solution. In most cases, it just covers up an issue by creating more issues (`specificity weight`).

Comment: When using bootstrap, sometimes you need to use `important` to work around certain situations, because bootstrap itself also uses `important` a lot.

Comment: Try this, without using `important`, but placing your `css` after the Bootstrap link